# Change Post Title For IOS Facebook Photo Post

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting photos to facebook from my iphone app just fine:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               _imageView.image,         @"picture",_facebookcomment.textView.text, @"message",
                               nil]; 
[appDelegate.facebookRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos/"
                                        andParams:params
                                    andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                      andDelegate:appDelegate];
```

However i want to change the title field of the post and add parameters in, for example as instagram does, above each photo you have:

[name] took a [photo] with [instagram]. Name, photo and instgram are all linked.

I've googled and worked through the fields in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/, such as 'from' and 'caption' but cant get the photo title to change. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [name] took a [photo] with [instagram].

I thing you’re looking for [Open Graph actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) here …

Comment: I've been looking through the facebook documentation as well. Trying to work out where this is set. It uses the FB application name at the moment.